# How to set up server for testing Facebook App locally

Tags: facebook

I am adding Facebook integration to an existing .NET site (using IIS 7) so that our users can post updates to Facebook but I'm having trouble initializing & testing the Facebook connection (via their JavascriptSDK) in my development environment. I've read several posts on stackoverflow relating to setup for local testing but it's hard to tell which are still relevant. And I develop on a server used by several other web developers, so I'm leery of the suggested etc/hosts changes affecting localhost.

My "network guy" wants to know exactly what kind of environment I need for development and for our self-hosted production server. Would this list sufficiently answer that request?

1. Firewall should allow communication with *.facebook.com -- ports 80 
   and 443
2. Use registered domain. (Or can I use test fully via the etc/hosts
   edits on a development server?)
3. Domain must have SSL enabled (Not sure whether we require
   this: we're not presenting our app within Facebook, only connecting 
   to gain user permission to post.)

Then on the Facebook App settings, am I correct in assuming that we don't need to supply an App Namespace?

Comment: Can you explain more about the setup you came up with and what it is you're trying to do? Why wouldn't you need to supply the *App Namespace* field? How do other developers share *localhost* with you?

Comment: @NitzanTomer -- The only Facebook action that we'll need to perform at this time is allowing the user to post a status update (e.g. "I exercised for 30 minutes this morning") from our .NET site. We will not be referring to our app from Facebook, nor presenting on a canvas within Facebook.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook API error 191](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191)

Comment: Using Facebook connect from localhost is *possible*, using the graph from localhost is *possible* and posting to the user's wall is also *possible*.

Comment: Usually *localhost* is used for the machine that you are working on, it's just *127.0.0.1*. Maybe you are mapping it to a server on your local network. As @ifaour wrote, you can use *localhost*, and you can also add it to *App Domain* in the settings. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Thank you both. I managed to get the Facebook integration working on my development server by applying the localhost.local solution to my Facebook App setup (Basic Info > App Domain = `localhost.local`, and Website > Site URL = `http://localhost.local`), IIS (new localhost.local site on port 80 and stopped other port 80 site), my hosts file (added "127.0.0.1 localhost.local") and VS 2010 (set my web app to "Use local IIS Web server" with Project Url = `http://localhost.local`). So my original #2 is not a requirement for development, but is the list correct for a production site?